# How to add optional parameter for echo.Bind?

Tags: go

Here is my code

```
ABC:= model.ABC{}
if err := c.Bind(&ABC); err != nil {}
```

`c` is echo.Context

Here is my model:

```
type ABC struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"int"`
}
```

I want the `Age` optional. So when I do not pass it in the body request. It still works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```golang
type ABC struct {
    Name string  `json:"name"`
    Age  *int    `json:"int"`
}
```

And remember check it before you use `Age` field:

```golang
a := ABC{}

// ...

if a.Age != nil {
 // Do something you want with `Age` field
}
```

Here is my demo for this question:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
)

type User struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Email *int   `json:"email"`
}

func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    e.POST("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        // return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!")
        u := new(User)
        if err := c.Bind(u); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, u)
    })

    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}
```

```bash
go run main.go
```

```bash
➜  curl -X POST http://localhost:1323 \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"name":"Joe"}'

{"name":"Joe","email":null}
➜  curl -X POST http://localhost:1323 \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"name":"Joe", "email": 11}'

{"name":"Joe","email":11}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Go does not support optional parameters out of the box. I see that you are using Gin, you can use

```golang
abc := ABC{}
if body, err := c.GetRawData(); err == nil {
        json.Unmarshal(body, abc)
}
```

This will set the value of the fields not passed in the request to zero values. You can then proceed to set the values to whatever is required.

Comment: Hi, I am using echo framework, I did mention `echo.Context` in the post